# Two way binding in dojox mvc - non dijit, parserExtention

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, dojo

I'm trying to create a "checkbox-tree" with dojox mvc , where unchecking the top most checkbox will uncheck the checkboxes below.
The databinding for the initial state/value of the checkboxes works fine, but when I through code change the model items visible property to false (the checkbox checked is bound to this property), the checkboxes remains checked.

I can see that the widget data-model has changed its value to false.

Fragment of my markup:

```
<script type="dojo/require">
        at: "dojox/mvc/at"
    </script>
    <input type="checkbox" data-mvc-bindings="value: at('rel:', 'id'), id: at('rel:', 'id'), checked: at('rel:', 'visible').direction(at.both)" />
```

I've also tried to set it's data value to false through chrome developer console but the checkbox remains checked

```
dijit.registry.byId("dojox_mvc_Templated_199").target
Object {id: "abc", name: "abc", legend: "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQA..truncated", visible: true, _watchCallbacks: function…}_watchCallbacks: function (a,b,d,r){var t=function(n){if(n){n=n.slice();for(var s=0,r=n.length;s<id: "abc"legend: "iVBORw0K4v5s/UwAAAAASUVORK5CYII="name: "abc"visible: false__proto__: Object

dijit.registry.byId("dojox_mvc_Templated_199").target.visible = false;
false
dijit.registry.byId("dojox_mvc_Templated_199").target
Object {id: "abc", name: "abc", legend: "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQA..truncated", visible: false, _watchCallbacks: function…}
```

Anyone know how I can achieve a two way binding like this?
The dojo documentation is very sparse, especially on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good to see you solved the problem yourself. From what I see in the code snippet, I’d just add one thing just in case: For the change watchers (e.g. `at()` in templates) to get change notified, you’ll need to use [`dojo/Stateful#set()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/Stateful.html#set) API (e.g. `stateful.set(“visible”, false)`) instead of directly setting a property (e.g. `stageful.visible = false`).

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I simply had to call `commit()` and `queryStore()` on my `EditStoreRefListController`

My model:

```
this.model = new EditStoreRefListController({
                store: new MemoryStore({ idProperty: "id", data: new StatefulArray() })
            });
```

So after doing changes on the model...

```
this.model.commit();
this.model.queryStore();
```